# Images as planes in Solid View Shading

Tags: modeling, image, sculpting

I was wondering if there is any way to load images as planes in a way that they are visible in solid view to use as a reference.
We know that loading images as planes make them easy to scale so it helps when we want to use those images as reference for modelling or sculpting. The problem is the texture is no visible in solid mode where modelling or sculpting is easier.

Loading the image as a reference is not as easy to manipulate.

If there is no way to do it at the moment is ok, I will just add a request in the Right-Click Select Discord Channel.

Bonus question. Is it possible so see through the back of an image as a plane or reference images so it doesn't interfere when we move the around the viewport looking for another point of view? I am thinking that setting up the mesh we are working in as SHOW->In Front could be a possible workaround.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Just gotta turn on textures mode in solid view.

Comment: That is a nice workaround, hahaha. So logical and simple.
Thanks for that, I should have thought about it.

Answer (score 4):

Before any requests read the manual on using images in empties.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/empties.html?highlight=image%20reference#image

---

If you want images as reference, don't use images as planes, use Add > Image > Reference.

[image]

This tool allows you to create an empty with an image associated with it, that ist is visible in Solid mode. It is not really an object with vertices or faces, and it will not render in the final image. Such image will appear in front of the geometry.

To have an image that shows behind the geometry, then use Add > Image > Background

You can always change how the image is displayed:

[image]

To resize the image to an exact size use  the Size controls for the properties of the empty.

[image]

Or use the sliders for scale to change the aspect ratio in whichever axis you need.

[image]

Images as planes is meant to be used when you need a plane with actual vertices and faces, that has an image mapped into the material.

Comment: This is a much better, more complete answer than mine.. wish I could pass over my UV's. I may delete mine, after a while.

Comment: Thanks for that. I might not explain myself properly. 
I know the feature use image as a reference. The problem is that this creates an image using an empty ( as you point out ) this makes it hard to scale the image to an accurate scale. With planes this is a way easier. That is the reason of my question.

That Size 5 metre I can see in your GIF doesn't work really well according to my tests.

Thanks so much anyway.

Comment: @ManuelGPz you can set the size of an image as empty with absolute precision using the size slider shown on the last image.

Comment: Thanks for that.